# window.open is not opening the right url file

Tags: internet-explorer

I Have this product info page where i have custom size option when user selects this option a new popup window opens. This popup windows opens perfectly fine with Firefox but its not loading the right file when using IE. in Firefox the file opens is http://www.gagatrendsonline.com/custom_size.php but when click the same link in the IE it opens http://www.gagatrendsonline.com/product/custom_size.php which is the wrong URL.
Please help.

Comment: can you share the code that you are using to call window.open and the url of the page it's triggered from? It may be a relative path problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting the URL, put a slash "/" in the beginning of the url string ...
example:

```
window.open('/custom_size.php');
```

With this, you will force the url to go to the root.